# I was trying to integrate tailwind into React Js and I got this error

Tags: reactjs, npm, frontend, tailwind-css

I was integrating tailwind into React Js using Postcss and autoprefixer.

This is the Error I get immediately after running npm start or npm run start

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ethniquecity@0.1.0 start: `npm run watch:css && react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ethniquecity@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be, you might have not added commands for compiling sass files in package.json. Here is the solution 
 **Before view of package.json file**

```js
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

**After view of package.json file**

```js
"scripts": {
  "start": "npm run watch:css && react-scripts start",
  "build": "npm run build:css && react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  "build:css": "postcss src/styles/global.css -o src/styles/main.css",
  "watch:css": "postcss src/styles/global.css -o src/styles/main.css"
},
```

Reference - [Webomnizz](https://webomnizz.com/setting-up-tailwindcss-with-react/)